# Fastest way to calculate difference in all columns

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe of all float columns. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12.0).reshape(3,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
#    A    B     C     D
# 0  0.0  1.0   2.0   3.0
# 1  4.0  5.0   6.0   7.0
# 2  8.0  9.0  10.0  11.0
```

I would like to calculate column-wise differences for all combinations of columns (e.g., A-B, A-C, B-C, etc.).

E.g., the desired output would be something like:

```
 A_B   A_C   A_D   B_C   B_D   C_D
-1.0  -2.0  -3.0  -1.0  -2.0  -1.0
-1.0  -2.0  -3.0  -1.0  -2.0  -1.0
-1.0  -2.0  -3.0  -1.0  -2.0  -1.0
```

Since the number of columns may be large, I'd like to do the calculations as efficiently/quickly as possible. I assume I'll get a big speed bump by converting the dataframe to a numpy array first so I'll do that, but I'm wondering if there are any other strategies that might result in large performance gains. Maybe some matrix algebra or multidimensional data format trick that results in not having to loop through all unique combinations. Any suggestions are welcome. This project is in Python 3.

Comment: For *A-B*, do you want an array `[-1,-1,-1]`? What ouput are you expecting from this?

Comment: I added some example output. I am looking for array/vector output for each set of columns, but it doesn't matter too much if those are standalone or collected in a list, multidimensional array, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listed in this post are two NumPy approaches for performance - One would be fully vectorized approach and another with one loop.

**Approach #1**

```
def numpy_triu1(df):          
    a = df.values
    r,c = np.triu_indices(a.shape[1],1)
    cols = df.columns
    nm = [cols[i]+"_"+cols[j] for i,j in zip(r,c)]
    return pd.DataFrame(a[:,r] - a[:,c], columns=nm)
```

Sample run -

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
     A    B     C     D
0  0.0  1.0   2.0   3.0
1  4.0  5.0   6.0   7.0
2  8.0  9.0  10.0  11.0

In [78]: numpy_triu(df)
Out[78]: 
   A_B  A_C  A_D  B_C  B_D  C_D
0 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -2.0 -1.0
1 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -2.0 -1.0
2 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -2.0 -1.0
```

**Approach #2**

If we are okay with array as output or dataframe without specialized column names, here's another -

```
def pairwise_col_diffs(a): # a would df.values
    n = a.shape[1]
    N = n*(n-1)//2
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum() ))
    start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
    out = np.empty((a.shape[0],N),dtype=a.dtype)
    for j,i in enumerate(range(n-1)):
        out[:, start[j]:stop[j]] = a[:,i,None] - a[:,i+1:]
    return out
```

---

**Runtime test**

Since OP has mentioned that multi-dim array output would work for them as well, here are the array based approaches from other author(s) -

```
# @Allen's soln
def Allen(arr):
    n = arr.shape[1]
    idx = np.asarray(list(itertools.combinations(range(n),2))).T
    return arr[:,idx[0]]-arr[:,idx[1]]

# @DYZ's soln
def DYZ(arr):
    result = np.concatenate([(arr.T - arr.T[x])[x+1:] \
            for x in range(arr.shape[1])]).T
    return result
```

`pandas` based solution from @Gerges Dib's post wasn't included as it came out very slow as compared to others.

Timings -

We will use three dataset sizes - `100`, `500` and `1000` :

```
In [118]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(3,100)))
     ...: a = df.values
     ...: 

In [119]: %timeit DYZ(a)
     ...: %timeit Allen(a)
     ...: %timeit pairwise_col_diffs(a)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 258 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 284 µs per loop

In [121]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(3,500)))
     ...: a = df.values
     ...: 

In [122]: %timeit DYZ(a)
     ...: %timeit Allen(a)
     ...: %timeit pairwise_col_diffs(a)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.56 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 39.9 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop

In [123]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(3,1000)))
     ...: a = df.values
     ...: 

In [124]: %timeit DYZ(a)
     ...: %timeit Allen(a)
     ...: %timeit pairwise_col_diffs(a)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.61 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 167 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.09 ms per loop
```

Comment: Sorry, is possible add timings for compare solutions?

Comment: @jezrael Added.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with NumPy. Let `arr=df.values`. First, let's find all two-column combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations    
column_combos = combinations(range(arr.shape[1]), 2)
```

Now, subtract columns pairwise and convert a list of arrays back to a 2D array:

```
result = np.array([(arr[:,x[1]] - arr[:,x[0]]) for x in column_combos]).T
#array([[1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.],
#       [1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.],
#       [1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.]])
```

Another solution is somewhat (~15%) **faster** because it subtracts whole 2D arrays rather than columns, and has fewer Python-side iterations:

```
result = np.concatenate([(arr.T - arr.T[x])[x+1:] for x in range(arr.shape[1])]).T
#array([[ 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.],
#       [ 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.],
#       [ 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.]])
```

You can convert the result back to a DataFrame if you want:

```
columns = list(map(lambda x: x[1]+x[0], combinations(df.columns, 2)))
#['BA', 'CA', 'DA', 'CB', 'DB', 'DC']

pd.DataFrame(result, columns=columns)
#    BA   CA   DA   CB   DB   DC
#0  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
#1  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
#2  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12.0).reshape(3,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_cols = df.columns.tolist()
#build a index array of all the pairs need to do the subtraction
idx = np.asarray(list(itertools.combinations(range(len(df_cols)),2))).T
#build a new DF using the pairwise difference and column names
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=df.values[:,idx[0]]-df.values[:,idx[1]], 
                      columns=[''.join(e) for e in (itertools.combinations(df_cols,2))])

df_new
Out[43]: 
    AB   AC   AD   BC   BD   CD
0 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -2.0 -1.0
1 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -2.0 -1.0
2 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -1.0 -2.0 -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how fast can this be compared to other possible methods, but here it is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12.0).reshape(3,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# get the columns as list
cols = list(df.columns)
# define output dataframe
out = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over possible periods
for period in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    names = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2, in zip(cols, cols[period:])]
    out[names] = df.diff(periods=period, axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all')

print(out)

# column name shows which two columns are subtracted

    AB   BC   CD   AC   BD   AD
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0
```